# Apply patch magento 1.7.x failed

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Check my site with Magento 1.7.x detected that would solve several problems patching the project. I did, clean the cache of my project but it has not worked yet.

Patch SUPEE-5345

```
bash PATCH_SUPEE-5345_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-02-10-08-11-22.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

Check the site because of https://www.magereport.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have successfully applied the patch no need to worry.

This message comes when you have successfully applied the patch on your magento.

See the attached screenshot.

[image: Successful patch installation screenshot]

Also check following file

`app/etc/applied.patches.list`  // This will be containing the changed files information.

If your patch updated files are in place then you have no need to worry about the results at  *https://www.magereport.com/*